# Electromagnetic wave equation in exponential refractive index

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

I’m trying to find the electromagnetic field of an electromagnetic wave in an exponential refractive index. What that means is the refractive index has the form $n\left(y\right)=e^{sy}$. I know for a fact that the electromagnetic wave should always have 100% transmittance when in a continuous refractive index, and as such we would only need to worry about one wave. My proof is as follows. Below is the equation for the total transmittance for a ray of light across a path.
$$T_{tot}=e^{\int_{a}^{b}{\ln{\left(k\left(x\right)\right)}dx}}$$
Where k is the transmittance per meter. So if the transmittance/m was on average 0.9, the transmittance after 2 meters is 0.81. Now all I’d have to do is prove k=1. According to Fresnel’s equations, the reflectance for s-polarized light is
$$R_s=\left(\frac{n_1\cos{\theta_i}-n_2\cos{\theta_t}}{n_1\cos{\theta_i}+n_2\cos{\theta_t}}\right)^2$$
And now we’ll convert things into more convenient formats.
$$\begin{matrix}\cos{\theta_i}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta_i}}&\cos{\theta_t}=\sqrt{1-\frac{n_1^2}{n_2^2}\sin^2{\theta_i}}\\\end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{matrix}n_1=1&n_2=1+x\\\end{matrix}$$
$$T_s=1-R_s=\frac{4n_1n_2\cos{\theta_i}\cos{\theta_t}}{\left(n_1\cos{\theta_i}+n_2\cos{\theta_t}\right)^2}=\frac{4n_1\sqrt{n_2^2-\left(n_1^2+n_2^2\right)\sin^2{\theta_i}+n_1^2\sin^4{\theta_i}}}{n_1^2\left(1-2\sin^2{\theta_i}\right)+n_2^2+2n_1\cos{\theta_i}\sqrt{n_2^2-n_1^2\sin^2{\theta_i}}}=\frac{4\sqrt{1+2x+x^2-\left(2+2x+x^2\right)\sin^2{\theta_i}+\sin^4{\theta_i}}}{2-2\sin^2{\theta_i}+2x+x^2+2\sqrt{\left(1+x\right)^2-\left(1+\left(1+x\right)^2\right)\sin^2{\theta_i}+\sin^4{\theta_i}}}=\frac{4\sqrt{1+2x+x^2-\left(2+2x+x^2\right)a^2+a^4}}{2-2a^2+2x+x^2+2\sqrt{1+2x+x^2-\left(2+2x+x^2\right)a^2+a^4}}=\frac{4\sqrt{\left(1-a^2\right)^2+2x\left(1-a^2\right)+x^2\left(1-a^2\right)}}{2-2a^2+2x+x^2+2\sqrt{\left(1-a^2\right)^2+2x\left(1-a^2\right)+x^2\left(1-a^2\right)}}=\frac{4\sqrt{\left(1-a^2\right)\left(\left(1-a^2\right)+2x+x^2\right)}}{2\left(1-a^2\right)+2x+x^2+2\sqrt{\left(1-a^2\right)\left(\left(1-a^2\right)+2x+x^2\right)}}=\frac{4\sqrt{b\left(b+2x+x^2\right)}}{2b+2x+x^2+2\sqrt{b\left(b+2x+x^2\right)}}$$
So now we have the transmittance. Since x will be very small,
$$T_s=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\left(\frac{4\sqrt{b\left(b+2x+x^2\right)}}{2b+2x+x^2+2\sqrt{b\left(b+2x+x^2\right)}}\right)}=1-\frac{x^2}{4b^2}$$
Here s represents the rate of the refractive index’s change over distance.$$x=e^\frac{s}{N}-1=\frac{s}{N}$$
$$T_s=1-\frac{s^2}{4N^2\cos^4{\theta_i}}$$
$$k=T_s^N=\left(1-\frac{s^2}{4N^2\cos^4{\theta_i}}\right)^N=\left(\frac{N^2-\frac{s^2}{4\cos^4{\theta_i}}}{N^2}\right)^N=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\left(1+\frac{c}{x^2}\right)^x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\left(1+cx^2\right)^\frac{1}{x}}=1$$
It’s the same in the p-polarized case.
$$R_p=\left(\frac{n_2\cos{\theta_i}-n_1\cos{\theta_t}}{n_2\cos{\theta_i}+n_1\cos{\theta_t}}\right)^2$$
The difference between it and the s-polarized case is the refractive indexes are swapped. This essentially has the effect of
$$\begin{matrix}n_1=1&n_2=1-x\\\end{matrix}$$
From there the calculation carries on as before but with a negative x. When it reaches the point where x is squared, the distinction completely disappears.
As for calculating the field, we must first find the correct phase function. At y=0, we will have the wave be entirely in the x+ direction. As y increases, it’ll move more in the y direction.
$$\begin{matrix}n\left(y\right)=e^{sy}&\varepsilon\left(y\right)=\varepsilon_0e^{sy}&\mu\left(y\right)=\mu_0e^{sy}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0c_0^2}e^{sy}\\\end{matrix}$$
$$Snell^\prime s\ Law:n_1\sin{\theta_1}=n_2\sin{\theta_2}$$
In our case this means
$$1=n\left(y\right)\sin{\theta}$$
So
$$\begin{matrix}\sin{\theta}=e^{-sy}&\cos{\theta}=\sqrt{1-e^{-2sy}}\\\end{matrix}$$
I’ve determined the phase to be
$$\phi=\frac{\omega}{c_0s}\left(sx+\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}-\tan^{-1}{\left(\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}\right)}\right)$$
The proof of that is as follows.
$$c=\frac{\omega}{\sqrt{\phi_x^2\left(x,y\right)+\phi_y^2\left(x,y\right)}}=\frac{\omega}{\frac{\omega}{c_0}\sqrt{1+e^{2sy}-1}}=c_0e^{-sy}$$
$$\sin{\theta}\hat{x}+\cos{\theta}\hat{y}=\frac{\left(\phi_x\left(x,y\right)\hat{x}+\phi_y\left(x,y\right)\hat{y}\right)}{\sqrt{\phi_x^2\left(x,y\right)+\phi_y^2\left(x,y\right)}}=\frac{c}{\omega}\left(\phi_x\left(x,y\right)\hat{x}+\phi_y\left(x,y\right)\hat{y}\right)=\frac{c_0e^{-sy}}{\omega}\left(\frac{\omega}{c_0}\hat{x}+\frac{\omega}{c_0}\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}\hat{y}\right)=e^{-sy}\hat{x}+\sqrt{1-e^{-2sy}}\hat{y}$$
So this phase function abides Snell’s law and has the correct speed of light. Lets now create our field equations and verify them with Maxwell’s equations.
$$\vec{E}=E_0A\left(y\right)\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\hat{z}$$
$$\vec{B}=\frac{E_0e^{sy}}{c_0}A\left(y\right)\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\left(\cos{\theta}\hat{x}-\sin{\theta}\hat{y}\right)=\frac{E_0}{c_0}A\left(y\right)\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\left(\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}\hat{x}-\hat{y}\right)$$
$$\vec{D}=\varepsilon_0E_0A\left(y\right)e^{sy}\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\hat{z}$$
$$\vec{H}=\varepsilon_0c_0E_0A\left(y\right)e^{-sy}\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\left(\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}\hat{x}-\hat{y}\right)$$
$$Maxwell^\prime s\ equations:\ \begin{matrix}\nabla\cdot\vec{D}=\rho_e&\nabla\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}\\\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0&\nabla\times\vec{H}=\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}\\\end{matrix}$$
$$\nabla\times\vec{E}=E_0\left(A_y\left(y\right)\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\hat{x}+A\left(y\right)\frac{\omega}{c_0}\cos{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\left(\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}\hat{x}-\hat{y}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}=-\frac{E_0\omega}{c_0}A\left(y\right)\cos{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\left(\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}\hat{x}-\hat{y}\right)$$
$$0=\nabla\times\vec{E}+\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}=E_0A_y\left(y\right)\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\hat{x}$$
As we can see, A(y) needs to be a constant.
$$\nabla\times\vec{H}=-\varepsilon_0c_0E_0\left(A\left(y\right)\left(\frac{\omega}{c_0}e^{sy}\cos{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}+\frac{se^{-sy}}{\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}}\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\right)+A_y\left(y\right)\sqrt{1-e^{-2sy}}\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\right)\hat{z}$$
$$\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}=-\varepsilon_0E_0\omega\ A\left(y\right)e^{sy}\cos{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\hat{z}$$
$$0=\nabla\times\vec{H}-\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}=-\varepsilon_0c_0E_0\sin{\left(\phi-t\omega\right)}\left(A\left(y\right)\left(\frac{se^{-sy}}{\sqrt{e^{2sy}-1}}\right)+A_y\left(y\right)\sqrt{1-e^{-2sy}}\right)\hat{z}$$
As you can see, the last equation is never 0. In order for this to be a solution to Maxwell’s equations, it needs to be 0. If anyone could help me figure out what I did wrong so I could find the correct solution, it’d be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that it is  " ... a fact that the electromagnetic wave should always have 100% transmittance when in a continuous refractive index, and as such we would only need to worry about one wave."?

Comment: @hyportnex I literally proved why immediately after I said that. The proof takes up like half of the post. I showed as N approached infinity, the transmittance per meter approached 100%.

Comment: You could not prove that statement in general because it is not true. Starting from $\rm{curl} H = \epsilon \mathfrak {j} \omega E$ and $\rm{curl E} = - \mu_0 \mathfrak{j} \omega H$, substitute the 1st  in the 2nd you get $\nabla^2 E + k_0^2 \epsilon _r E = - \rm{grad}(E \rm{grad} \rm{ln}(\epsilon))$. Unless the RHS, specifically the gradient of $\rm{ln}(\epsilon)$  is negligible you cannot claim simple wave propagation.